# Invalid table name error while using Execute Immediate statement with bind variables

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, dynamic-sql, execute-immediate

I'm trying to get this dynamic SQL running ( using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`)

```
M_SQL_STATEMENT := 'SELECT MAX(:m_var1)+1 from :m_var2 RETURNING MAX(:m_var1)+1 INTO :m_var3';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE M_SQL_STATEMENT
   USING M_COLUMN_NAME, UPPER(P_TABLE_NAME), M_COLUMN_NAME
   RETURNING INTO M_SEQ_NUMBER;
```

However, when trying to run this, I keep running into

```
ORA-00903: Invalid table
```

P_TABLE_NAME is a table name which is accepted as an input. I have confirmed that the table name & the column name are valid. I can't figure out why Oracle is throwing the error.

FWIW Altering the SQL statement to

```
M_SQL_STATEMENT := 'SELECT MAX(:m_var1)+1 SEQ from :m_var2 RETURNING SEQ INTO :m_var3';
```

still results in the same error.

Comment: Related: [Why cannot I use bind variables in DDL/SCL statements in dynamic SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25489002/1461424)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put the table name and column name into the dynamic SQL, so something like

```
M_SQL_STATEMENT := 'SELECT MAX(' || M_COLUMN_NAME || ')+1 from ' 
|| P_TABLE_NAME';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE M_SQL_STATEMENT INTO M_SEQ_NUMBER;
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to use/pass table & column names as bind variables?

Comment: No it's not, that's kind of the whole reason to use dynamic SQL in the first place :-)

Comment: Thanks, @GregReynolds for some reason I thought that was possible

Comment: BTW, @GregReynolds - got this working. Couple of mistakes though, - the SQL should be `'SELECT MAX(' || M_COLUMN_NAME || ')+1 from ' 
|| P_TABLE_NAME;` and the execute immediate should not have "returning" - like so --> `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE M_SQL_STATEMENT
INTO M_SEQ_NUMBER;`

Comment: Great news. I will change the answer